# SetInterval Not working as Expected in my HTML task

Tags: javascript, html

I'm to write a function, such that when the Start Timer button is clicked, the h1 text counts down from 10 to 0. So, when the button is clicked, after 1 second, the text changes to 9, then after another second, it changes to 8, then 7, then 6, and so on, and the timer stops at 0. Additionally, when the countdown timer starts, the button is disabled, then when the timer elapses at 0, enable the button again.

I have written some code below but I don't know what I'm not doing right.

My code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>10</h1>
    <button onclick='execute()'>Start Timer</button>
</body>
<script>
    let count = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML;
    setInterval(function execute() {
     count--
h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = count;
btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
if(count <= 0){
    btn.disabled = true;
}
    }, 1000);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: `count` is a string. setTimeout runs ONCE. your title says setInterval, but your code says setTimeout!

Comment: I changed the setTimeout to setInterval and the result keeps decreasing but it should only work when the button is clicked. and stops working when the value gets to zero

Comment: well you do not have a function named execute around the code.... And you need to learn how to use clearInterval...

Comment: If you check the code you will see the execute function inside the setInterval

Comment: Well setInterval does not care about that.... you need to wrap it.

Comment: Please how do I wrap it

Comment: `function execute() { var myInterval = setInterval(function (){}); }`

Answer (score 0):

> The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

setTimeout() is not a loop method

if you want to make a loop using setTimeout() :

```
 setTimeout(function execute() {
     count--
     h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = count;
     btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
     if(count <= 0){
       btn.disabled = true;
     }
     else{
        execute() // <- call your function again
      }
    }, 1000);
```